# C++, diamond inheritance, where/when do pure virtuals need to be implemented?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

C++: I have a base class A with a pure virtual function f() and then two classes B and C inherit virtually from A, and a class D that inherits from both B and C (the typical diamond structure):

```
   A f() = 0
 v/ \v
 B   C
  \ /
   D
```

Where and when does f() = 0 need to be implemented in the following cases?

1. Both B and C have also pure virtual functions (-> do abstract classes *must* implement inherited pure virtuals?)
2. Only one of them (B XOR C) has a pure virtual function (-> does the other still *must* implement f()?)
3. Neither B nor C have pure virtuals of their own (-> possible way to skip implementation in B and C and "pass it through" to D?)
4. In which of the three above cases does D need to implement f()? In which cases is it optionally for D to implement f()? In which cases, if any, is it not possible for D to implement f()?

Are there any other common suggestions for these kind of problems?

Thanks.

Comment: @Tux-D What? This is maybe a possible case for a real-life project I'm working on. I'm still thinking of several approaches.

Comment: I usually consider diamond inheritance to be bad design. Sure it's possible but there is usually a better way. Multiple inheritance is best with pure virtual base classes.

Comment: I agree with AJG85. If you have the diamond inheritance pattern, you should rethink your design.

Comment: "_I usually consider diamond inheritance to be bad design._" Why? "_with pure virtual base classes._" What is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both B and C have also pure virtual functions (-> do abstract classes must implement inherited pure virtuals?)

**Yes** `D` **MUST** implement **ALL** the inherited pure virtual functions.
Unless a class implements all the pure virtual functions of the classes it derives from the class itself actas as an Abstract class.

> Only one of them (B XOR C) has a pure virtual function (-> does the other still must implement f()?)

`D` will have to implement the pure virtual function it inherits through its Base classes in any hierarchy. If its immediate Base class does not define a Pure virtual function, then that class becomes an Abstract class too, and unless `D` implements the inherited pure virtual function, it will become Abstract too.

> Neither B nor C have pure virtuals of their own (-> possible way to skip implmentation in B and C and "pass it through" to D?)

`D` will have to implement the the pure virtual functions it inherits through `A->B` & `A-C`.Note that in this case both `B` and `C` will be Abstract classes.

> In which of the three above cases does D need to implement f()? In which cases is it optionally for D to implment f()? In which cases, if any, is it not possible for D to implement f()?

`D` needs to implement `foo()` in all the above 3 conditions, to be able to be instantiable(Non-Abstract).

**Conclusion:**

1. A class needs to implement ALL the pure virtual functions it inherits from ALL it's base classes, failing to do so will make the class an Abstract class.
2. Virtual attribute is inherited, If a Super class declares a function virtual then the overridden function in the derived class is virtual too and it passes down the virtual attribute to all classes deriving from it.

---

Avoid the **Diamond of Death**! Unless you really understand the subtleties involved with it. A lot of people try to use virtual Inheritance when it is not really the most apt way to achieve what their design wants to achieve. The use of Virtual Inheritance is indeed necessary in some scenarios, it is nevertheless an important construct provided by the language, but more often used in wrong ways. So it makes sense to revisit your design once to verify if you really need virtual Inheritance.

Following might be a good read:

1. **[Multiple Inheritance - Part I](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/037.htm)**
2. **[Multiple Inheritance - Part II](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/038.htm)**
3. **[Multiple Inheritance - Part III](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/039.htm)**

Comment: Just that I get it right: If A has a pure virtual function and B and C both do *not* implement it, then they are automatically abstract, too?

Comment: @Mahesh And if B and C both implement the pure virtual function, then D still does have to implement it? Id does not inherit one of the implementations from B or C?

Comment: @bluebernd: `D` needs to have a "unique final override", whichever way you implement it.

Comment: If `A` has a pure virtual, `D` must implement it, regardless of what `B` and `C` do.  If either `B` or `C` (or both) fail to implement it, `D` would be abstract without implementing it.  If both `B` and `C` implement it, the function is ambiguous in `D`; `D` must implement it to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: A nice answer **until** we get below the line.  Virtual inheritance is a tool, just like any other, and diamond shaped inheritance is valid in many cases.  Mixins, obviously, but see Barton & Nackman for other cases.

Comment: @James: You are indeed correct on that, `virtual Inheritance` is necessary in some cases but more often people tend to use it when it is not really required. I should have expressed that in better words.I have had that mushy feeling eversince I wrote that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Both B and C have also pure virtual functions (-> do abstract classes must implement inherited pure virtuals?

Yes. Any class that is inherited from abstract class **must** implement virtual functions to be able to instantiate. Or else they will also be abstract.

> Only one of them (B XOR C) has a pure virtual function (-> does the other still must implement f()?)

Since `C` also derived from `A`, it should also implement `f()`.

> Neither B nor C have pure virtuals of their own (-> possible way to skip implmentation in B and C and "pass it through" to D?)

You can do that. But that prevents instantiation of `B` or `C` alone like -

```
A *obj = new B(); // Error
A *obj = new C(); // Error
```

> In which of the three above cases does D need to implement f()? In which cases is it optionally for D to implment f()? In which cases, if any, is it not possible for D to implment f()?

`f()` can be implemented in `D` alone as long as you do want all of it's parent classes to be abstract.

Comment: The OP never says whether he actually wants to instantiate either `B` or `C`, though.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - It's a problem mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement is that at the "leaf" level (the most derived one) everything has an implementation (and possibly one only, otherwise ambiguity can arise if -at the point you access the graph- there are more implementation at a same "distance".

So D must implement everything has not been implemented yet, or everything has been implemented more than once through different paths (to disambiguate).
If something -at D level- is still left unimplemented ... D cannot be instatiated, and the implementation is demanded to and E, derived from D.

*- Diamonds are forever -*

Answer (score 0):

1. No, abstract classes (presumably `B` and `C`) don't need to implement inherited pure virtuals. A child class like `D` will need to do so to be instantiated though.
2. No, again `B` and `C` will inherit the pure virtual method and it need only be overridden to generate a final concrete class.
3. Yes, this would pass through implementation to `D`, in one of two ways. If `B` and `C` both inherit virtually, then `D` would implement it once. If they don't inherit virtually then `D` would need to override *both* the `B` and `C` versions of `f` to be concrete.
4. If `D` is abstract it never needs to implement `f`. Assuming you mean it to be concrete, in all three cases you'd need to override `f` in `D`. Only if both `B` and `C` override `f` would `D` not need to.

Take a long look at your design and remove the diamond inheritance. In most cases that's going to be your best bet to prevent all these sorts of issues.